# Can't deploy UWP app to xbox one

Tags: win-universal-app, xbox-one

So I have setup my Xbox One as a dev device and actually was able to run my app on my Xbox, but in order to use some new APIs to turn off scaling and what not I had to change my app target version to Build 14332. Unfortunately, after doing this, I am now not able to publish or debug my app to my Xbox and I am not getting very helpful clues as to why not.

I even reverted the target version back to Build 10240 but I am still getting this error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed. Deployment Register
>   operation with target volume C: on Package
>   MyCompany.MyApp_1.1.19.0_x64__5wbv4ypmprn7c from:
>   (AppxManifest.xml)  failed with error 0x80070002. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app
>   deployment issues. (0x80073cf9)   MyCompany.MyApp

EDIT: I found a work around. Restart my Xbox One. Literally, every time I run my app, I have to restart my Xbox One! :(

Comment: What 'new' APIs are you trying to use - can you show some code?

Answer (score 3):

I came across the same issue, and while restarting the console didn't help me, I did find another workaround: go to Dev Home and clicked `Remove all Visual Studio pairings`. I was able to deploy right after doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into the really similar problem, however with running on the remote machine. The solution was the same as [Pedro Pombeiro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209726/pedro-pombeiro) did on his Xbox One. I opened Windows `Settings` > `Update & Security` > `For developers` and `Unpair All`. Problem was solved and I could deploy and run the app on remote PC.